# How can I make a vector MPI datatype independent of the count?

Tags: c, types, mpi

I have data with stride 2 (for example) and I would like to send this data through several messages of different *length*.

If the number of elements (to `count`) were fixed I could simply [create a vector type](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Type_vector.html) that includes the count. This works:

```
    int stride = 2;
    MPI_Datatype type;
    MPI_Type_vector(count, 1, stride, MPI_INT, &type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&type);
    MPI_Send(buffer, 1, type, 1, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // or Recv
```

(note I am passing `1` to `MPI_Send`.)

However if `count` is variable (for example in a loop that changes count for fixed stride = 2) I will have to create and commit a datatype for each length.

I thought I could defined a single type with a unit count and put the count in the message send function itself but in my tests the result is different:

```
    int stride = 2;
    MPI_Datatype type;
    MPI_Type_vector(1, 1, stride, MPI_INT, &type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&type);
    MPI_Send(buffer, count, type, 1, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // or Recv
```

This code above doesn't do the same as the first code, therefore I deduce the count has a different meaning in the datatype and in the message call.

**How can I create a stride datatype that is independent of the count?**

---

This code is closer to the goal scenario. This works if I put count in the datatype creation and put all the code inside the loop.

```
    int stride = 2;
    MPI_Datatype type;
    MPI_Type_vector(1, 1, stride, MPI_INT, &type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&type);
    for(int count = 1; count != N; ++count){
        MPI_Send(buffer + count*10, count, type, 1, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // or Recv
    }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, all you need is to `MPI_Type_create_resized(MPI_INT, 0, stride*sizeof(int), &type); MPI_Type_commit(&type)`, and then you can simply `MPI_Send(buffer, count, type, ...)` in order to send `{buffer[0], buffer[stride], ..., buffer[stride*(count - 1)]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR You need to resize the vector datatype using `MPI_Type_create_resized` to include a gap of `stride - 1` elements at the end.

First, you have the arguments to the type contructor in the wrong order - the stride comes after the block length, i.e., it should be `MPI_Type_vector(1, 1, stride, MPI_INT, &type)`. But fixing this is not enough to make it work with multiple blocks and some understanding of the MPI datatypes is necessary.

An MPI datatype is simply a list of primitive types and their corresponding offsets known as its type map. When you tell MPI to send an element of type `type` from location `buffer`, the library iterates over the type map and reads a value of each primitive type from a location relative to `buffer` specified by the corresponding offset. For example, a datatype with type map `{(int,0),(char,6)}` results in MPI reading an `int` from location `buffer + 0` and a `char` from location `buffer + 6` (those are byte offsets). Offsets can be both positive and negative. Predefined MPI datatypes such as `MPI_INT` have type maps that constist of a single entry placing a value of the corresponding language type at offset 0, i.e., `{(int,0)}`.

There are two fundamental properties of each MPI datatype - its lower bound (LB) and its extent. The lower bound is the lowest offset in the type map. The extent is the difference between (highest offset + size of the primitive datatype located there + alignment padding) and the lower bound. It is possible to override both the LB and the extent with arbitrary values and thus change the apparent shape of the datatype. The latter is important when sending/receiving arrays of the datatype since MPI uses `buffer + i * extent` as the location of the *i*-th element to read/write, therefore having the right extent is crucial.

When you create a vector type with a given stride, MPI sets the elements of the type map in such a way as to leave the proper gaps in between the blocks, but it doesn't leave a gap at the end of the last block. A vector of `MPI_INT` with stride `stride`, block count `1`, and block length `1` is exactly the same as `MPI_INT`, even if `stride` is more than `1`. Indeed, if you read into the [MPI standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) (section 4.7, page 87), it says that `MPI_Type_vector(1, count, n, oldtype, &newtype)` is equivalent to `MPI_Type_contiguous(count, oldtype, &newtype)` for any value of `n`.

To make it actually work, you need to tell MPI to artificially inflate the extent in order to include the gap at the end. This is done using `MPI_Type_create_resized`. If the blocks are of length `1`, you can simply resize the original predefined datatype as shown in Gilles' comment:

```c
MPI_Datatype type;
MPI_Type_create_resized(MPI_INT, 0, stride * sizeof(int), &type);
MPI_Type_commit(&type);
```

Otherwise, you need to first create the vector type and then resize it:

```c
MPI_Datatype type1, type;
MPI_Type_vector(1, count, stride, MPI_INT, &type1);
MPI_Type_create_resized(type1, 0, stride * sizeof(int), &type);
MPI_Type_free(&type1);
MPI_Type_commit(&type);
```

You can now use `type` to `MPI_Send`/`MPI_Recv` with arbitrary send/receive counts.

Comment: Yes, put the stride argument in the wrong place in the example code. Thanks for reading my mind. This understanding solved my problem.

I see, I guess I wasn't taking figures like these literally enough https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/mpi-data.html#Vectortype . In some cases it was plainly wrong then, like this https://images.app.goo.gl/DC77VYktNtrCEVY29.

In summary it looks like it is always good to use vector plus resize to have a *composable* type, specially when working with strided arrays.

Comment: Setting the extent explicitly is necessary in several cases, including when creating struct datatypes with padding at the end.